# WiX Toolset manipulating sequence

Tags: wix

The project team has made the main.exe file available for managing its Windows service. The calling parameter in the .bat is like this:

```
main.exe (un)install
```

I am new to WiX Toolset, I managed to add the necessary files into feature.wxs using IsWiX extension. Now I want to alter the sequence like this:

1. Install the files to appropriate location.
2. (or 3.) Call `main.exe uninstall` first and determine its success.
3. (or 2.) Register the software in control panel.
4. Calling `main.exe install` and determine its success.

If possible, I'd also love to add the command `main.exe uninstall` when invoking MSI uninstallation.

I really **don't** want WiX itself to manage service (un)installation. What should I do to alter the sequence in the XML? By the way, I don't have any C# skills but I know people in my team can.

FYI, The structure of the WiX project is like this:

````
ProjectSolution
    |
    ```+ MainProject
    |
    ```SetupMergeModule
    |     |
    |     SetupMergeModule.wxs
    |     SetupMergeModuleCustom.wxs
    ```[Others]
    |
    ```MSISetup
          |
           ```Code
          |    |
          |    Feature.wxs
          |    Product.wxs
          ``` [Others]
````

I am using the latest stable release 3.8.

Comment: "I really don't want WiX itself to manage service (un)installation"—actually, it would be Windows Installer since this is standard functionality. So, doing it yourself is outside the intended use of Windows Installer. Perhaps you don't want to be using Windows Installer.

Comment: @TomBlodget Because the project team has already made it available via commandline `main.exe install` and `main.exe uninstall`. I don't want to do the extra work. I did a bit of research and tried CustomAction and it worked (not as expected due to VS issue but it's a progress).

Comment: Duplicating standard Windows Installer functionality is extra work and error prone. I encourage you to learn it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ServiceInstall element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/serviceinstall.html) to install services.

Comment: Hi my question is how can I call a series of specifc commands when files are copied over, while the installation process is on-going.